# How can I run an ansible role locally?

Tags: ansible

I want to build a docker image locally and deploy it so it can then be pulled on the remote server I'm deploying to.  To do this I first need to check out code from git to be built.

I have an existing role which installs git, sets up keys for reading from our repo etc.  I want to run this role locally to check out the code I care about.

I looked at local action, delegate_to, etc but haven't figured out an easy way to do this.  The best approach I could find was:

```yaml
- name: check out project from git
  delegate_to: localhost
  include_role: 
    name: configure_git
```

However, this doesn't work I get a complaint that there is a syntax error on the name line.  If I remove the delegate_to line it works (but runs on the wrong server).  If I replace include_role with debug it will run locally.  It's almost as if ansible explicitly refuses to run an included role locally, not that I can find that anywhere in the documentation.

Is there a clean way to run this, or other roles, locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract from the [`include_role` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html)

> - Task-level keywords, loops, and conditionals apply only to the `include_role` statement itself.
> - To apply keywords to the tasks within the role, pass them using the `apply` option or use `ansible.builtin.import_role` instead.
> - Ignores some keywords, like `until` and `retries`.

I actually don't know if the error you get is linked to `delegate_to` being ignored (I seriously doubt it is the case...). Meanwhile it's not the correct way to use it here:

```yaml
- name: check out project from git
  include_role: 
    name: configure_git
    apply:
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Moreover, this is most probably a bad idea. Let's imagine your play targets 100 servers: the role will run one hundred time (unless you also apply `run_once: true`). I would run my role "normally" on `localhost` in a dedicated play then do the rest of the job on my targets in the next one(s).

```yaml
- name: Prepare env on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: configure_git

- name: Do the rest on other hosts
  hosts: my_group
  
  tasks:
    - name: dummy.
      debug:
        msg: "Dummy"
```